# Handling unknown number of form values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which, besides other properties, has a link, which will open a modal window to enter additional information. The additional information is unknown when the form is generated, so I need to generate these items once they have been created. I was thinking I might append a `<form>` and then wrap a `<div>` to every pair of data entered in `<div>`, and then calculate how much data is entered.

My form looks like this
[image]

My question is: h**ow would you handle this scenario?**
Please ask if I left something unclear.

Comment: Is it always the same structure for all additional data? Do you add data using javascript?

Comment: it's always the same structure, only two properties (two strings). I was thinking using js, but I'm open to any sugg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seemed js specific , so i have not added any of the asp mvc stuff in the snippet and just worked around for the functionality of adding the shoes. You will obviously have to take into account that the list needs to be posted back to the server to save the changes. Which i think was outside the scope of this question

```js
$(function (){
  
  
  // Shoe add
  $('#saveValue').click(function(){
    
    // Get shoe name
    var shoeName = $('.modal-body input:first').val();
    // Get shoe number
    var shoeNum = $('.modal-body input:last').val();

    // Create structure to add to list 
     $('#addedValues ul').append("<li> Shoe Name: <strong>" + shoeName + "</strong><br /> Shoe Number <strong>" + shoeNum + "</strong></li> <hr />");
    
    $('#valuesModal').modal('hide');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top:30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    
    <form>
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="First Name" />     
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="First Name" />
        </div>
      
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      
      </form>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#valuesModal"> Add new pair </button>
    </div>
    <div id="addedValues">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>  
  
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="valuesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Shoe</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        <form>
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Shoe Name" />     
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Shoe Number" />
        </div>
      
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveValue">Save Shoe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each additional form creating you give it a name like array for instance..

```
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
<input type="number" name="number[]"/>
```

Then you can additional ones, then loop it on the server side